# Finding number of divisors

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of divisors of the form$4$$n$$+$$2$$($$n$ is non negative$)$of the integer $2$$4$$0$.please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll recommend you using divisor function, You can write 240 in terms of prime numbers as : $(2)^4*(3)^2*(5)$
Now number of divisors are: (p+1)(q+1)(r+1) where p,q,r are powers of prime numbers.
which here is (4+1)(2+1)(1+1)= 30 divisors.
By the way these are the total number of divisors, hope you can carry on ?
[Divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition)

Comment: Some care is needed here: $\;240=2^4\cdot3\cdot5\;$ and not what you wrote. Anyway, how can possibly help the OP to know how many divisors at all $\;240\;$ has? He wants divisors of a very particular form:  even ones that aren't divisors of four.